# Possessory vs Proprietary as adjectives

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms

Posessory (embolded) and Proprietary (embolded and italicized) here can't be synonyms, because the author is using them in opposition. Notice the "rather than" in the sentence footnoted 54. Thus how does Possessory differ from Proprietary?

> Secondly, if a third party steals the trust property, the beneficiary has no claim in the tort
> of conversion against the third party,<sup>53</sup> whereas the trustee would. The beneficiary would
> be able to sue in conversion if they had been in possession of the property, but then the
> beneficiary would be relying on their **possessory right** rather than their equitable ***proprietary
> right***.<sup>54</sup> Similarly, where the property is negligently damaged, the beneficiary has no
> direct claim against the tortfeasor for property damage or economic loss, because such a
> claim can be brought only by a person who has a legal **proprietary interest** or **possessory
> interest** in the property.<sup>55</sup>  A claim can be brought if the trustee is made a party to the proceedings,<sup>56</sup> but not if the trustee consented to the interference with the property, because
> then the third party will not have committed any wrong.

Virgo, *The Principles of Equity & Trusts* 2020 4th edn. Page 49. All boldings and italics are mine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proprietary https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/possessory

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Did you read those links yourself? The first definition of "proprietary" is "one that possesses, owns, or holds exclusive right to something". This looks the same as "possessory". And I'm asking about the legal definitions here, not ordinary English.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Questions about legal terms are explicitly on-topic here, even if they could also be answered on ELU or another SE site.

Answer (score 2):

**proprietary** = under legal ownership (whereas factual possession may not necessarily be happening)

**possessory** = under factual legal possession but with no legal ownership

Comment: Can you pls elaborate? Your answer baffles me.  1. You wrote " factual possession" for **proprietary**. Then you wrote "factual legal possession " for **possessory**. Did you typo? 2. What does "factual possession" mean exactly?

Comment: @ElVaf 1. No typo. Do you see and understand the words "_may not necessarily be happening_"? 2. It's when you have the property physically in your hands and control. You may or may not be the legal owner at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. What is "factual possession"?